# Snatch a daily comic and store it locally

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, wget, copying

I want to copy the daily comic from www.explosm.net/comics and store in a local folder.

The comics have unique names, and stored at several locations depending on the creator.

Like this:

- www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Rob/comic1.png
- www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Dave/comic2.png

However, every daily comic is available through the same url, www.explosm.net/comics, which redirects you to the newest comic available. Not sure if this is of any use, though.

I've experienced a little with the wget command together with cron to achieve this, but my lack of knowledge didn't yield me any satisfactory results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). What you want is a script which invokes cURL to obtain the page source served by the server when you request www.explosm.net/comics. Then you'd parse the returned data looking for the `img` tag which displays the comic.

After you have the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in question, you can make another request using cURL to actually download the image and save the returned data to a file, locally.

It appears that the source of the actual comic image, the one you're looking for starts with `http://www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics` so you can use a regular expression such as the following to determine the URL of the image you want to download.

```
src\=\"(http:\/\/www\.explosm\.net\/db\/files\/Comics\/[^"]*)\"
```

The URL is going to be the first group in the matches.

Comment: Alright. I've tried looking into cURL, but at first glimpse it seems to be way over my head. I may add that I'm rather new to linux. Though, if I manage to pull of what you're referring to, it might be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: well, do you have any knowledge of programming?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes, I have some (HTML/CSS/PHP, and I sorta know how regex works). Trying to expand my linux' as we speak. Though, I'm always open for new things - which why I wanted to try this. I just don't really know where to start.

Comment: update: figured out how to use curl. however, when i try to snatch http://www.explosm.net/comics/ (also tried comics/new/) it doesn't work. however if i try and snatch http://www.explosm.net/comics/2343/ (newest current comic) it works. how can i always make sure i snatch the latest page?

Comment: @habitats, first of all, if you know a bit of PHP, you can use the [PHP bindings for cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and create a php script to accomplish what you want. then, you can [create a daily cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) to invoke your php script every day to get the most recent comic. As to the reason some URLs don't workis probably because the ones that don't work are redirects and you haven't specified the options for cURL to follow redirects. See [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)